# Properly configure NPM package which depends on local packages

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, symlink, npm-install

I have this three local npm packages: `C:\projects\A`, `C:\projects\B` and `C:\projects\main`. `Main` is React app which is built with Webpack. `Main` depends on `A` and `B`, also `A` depends on `B`. We have our own "global" package manager which guarantees that packages will be located in same parent folder.

I want to suit these:

1. Node's (and webpack's) `require` will resolve local packages
2. I don't need to `npm install` in `Main` every time I change `A` or `B`

I did this in `Main`'s `package.json`:

```
....
"dependencies": {
    "A": "file:../A",
    "B": "file:../B",
    "react": ...
    .........
```

But ran into strange problem: `npm` doesn't install all packages in `A`'s and `B`'s node_modules, so Webpack build fails. And I need to run `npm install` each time.

I googled and found [linklocal](https://github.com/timoxley/linklocal), which replaces all local packages as symlinks. But ran into another problem:

> linklocal does not install dependencies of linked dependencies, as such you typically end up installing dependencies of linked dependencies twice: once during npm install, then again after linklocal

So I ran `linklocal` and then `npm install` again in `postinstall` script. But npm@3 didn't do anything with symlinked folders:

```
npm WARN update-linked node_modules/A needs updating to 1.0.0 from 1.0.0 but we can't, as it's a symlink
```

Then I decided to modify `postinstall` to go to every symlinked module and run `npm install` from there. And it worked at first sight: installing ran well, as well as webpack bunding. But Webpack started bundling two copies of React (which is prohibited).

How to configure my packages properly?

Answer (score 1):

In package A and package B you can have a **preinstall** script that execute **webpack**. This should resolve all the dependencies. 
On your main package you should link to the **dist**(build) folder of package A and B. 
 Also check this library [wml](https://github.com/wix/wml), it can help you to keep in sync your local dependencies.

 package.json:

`"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "webpack"
  }`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to build Main in other machines you could just do something like that in your project/Main

```
let C = require('C:\projects\A\index.js')
```

Or you could have a branch with

```
require('C:\projects\A\index.js')
```

And another with:

```
require('C')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) locally to maintain symlinks to your local development versions..

So, reset the `package.json` in `Main` to point to wherever the published packages will actually live:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "A": "<PUBLISHED_PACKAGE_REPO>",
    "B": "<PUBLISHED_PACKAGE_LOCATION>",
    "react": ...
```

This ensures that your project will always build on CI / other machines etc.

Then, navigate to your "project A" directory and create a link:

```
cd projects\A
npm link
```

This will create an npm specific symlink that points to `C:\projects\A`.

Then do the same for the B project:

```
cd projects\B
npm link
```

You now have both project links created, and just need to actually link them to your `Main` project:

```
cd projects\Main
npm link A
npm link B
```

If `A` also depends on `B` you simply need to link those projects too:

```
cd projects\A
npm link B
```

When you're finished developing and want to use whatever is specified in `package.json` just unlink and install:

```
cd projects\Main
npm unlink A
npm unlink B
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [npm pack](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) to package my dependencies and then install them in my main project using `npm install ./path/to/pack/result.tgz as detailed [here](http://podefr.tumblr.com/post/30488475488/locally-test-your-npm-modules-without-publishing)

It avoid to publish every changes made to A and B but does not prevent you to

> `npm install` in `Main` every time I change `A` or `B`